# Update Table with auto incrementing dates in date column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I want to update a Table with auto incrementing dates in date column in Sql server 2005.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To label newly inserted rows, you could combine an `identity` column with a calculated field.  For example:

```
declare @t table 
(
     dayNumber int identity, 
     Date as dateadd(day, dayNumber-1, '1970-01-01')
)

insert into @t default values
insert into @t default values
insert into @t default values

select * from @t
```

This prints:

```
dayNumber  Date
1          1970-01-01 00:00:00.000
2          1970-01-02 00:00:00.000
3          1970-01-03 00:00:00.000
```

---

To update columns in an existing table with increasing dates, use `row_number`, like:

```
declare @t2 table (id int identity, name varchar(50), DateColumn datetime)

insert @t2 (name) values ('Maggie'), ('Tom'), ('Phillip'), ('Stephen')

update  t2 
set     DateColumn = DATEADD(day, rn-1, '1970-01-01')
from    @t2 t2
join    (
        select  ROW_NUMBER() over (order by id) rn
        ,       id
        from    @t2 
        ) t2_numbered
on      t2_numbered.id = t2.id

select * from @t2
```

This prints:

```
id  name     DateColumn
1   Maggie   1970-01-01 00:00:00.000
2   Tom      1970-01-02 00:00:00.000
3   Phillip  1970-01-03 00:00:00.000
4   Stephen  1970-01-04 00:00:00.000
```